# How do i read a large SOLR response object by object while the response is still returning

Tags: javascript, solr

I'm querying SOLR7.5 for some large objects and would like to render them to a Browser UI as they are returned.

What are my options for reading the response bit by bit using when using the select request handler

Comment: What do you mean reading a response bit by bit? As in gets pages of results one after the other, as opposed to waiting and then getting them all in 1 block? If so, I don't know any wait to do that natively in Solr, but it's pretty easy to simulate it with a series of API queries, modifying the starting row.

Comment: my poor phrasing. i want to be able to process the response stream as it arrives. not wait until the entire response is received.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i was looking in the wrong place. I just needed to read up on my webAPI fetch().
the response.json() reads the response to completion.

response.body.getReader() allows you to grab the stream in chunk and decode it from there.

```
let test = 'https://my-solr7/people/select?q=something'
fetchStream(test);

function fetchStream(uri, params = {}){
  const options = {
    method: 'GET',
  };
  var decoder = new TextDecoder();
  fetch(uri, options)
  .then ()
  .then( (response) => {
  let read;
  const reader = response.body.getReader();
  reader.read()
    .then(read = (result) => {
      if (result.done) return;
      console.log(result.value);
      let chunk = decoder.decode(result.value || new Uint8Array, {stream: !result.done});
      console.log(chunk)
      reader.read().then(read);
    });
});
```

}

Comment: Nice. If this resolves your question make sure to mark it as the right answer :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is anything native to Solr to do what you are asking.

One approach to handle this would be to return only the ID of the documents that match the criteria in your query (and not include the heavy part of the document) and then fetch the large part of the document asynchronously from the client.

Comment: Thanks Heckor, I was approaching it from the wrong angle. Solr behaves as any web api. i needed to access my response stream directly.